# Why facet cells/umbrella cells of uroepithilium are sometimes multinucleated?

Tags: histology

Why do are they multinucleated and why only some cells, why not all?

Comment: Can you add a source where you obtained this information? Is it a question on the human urogenital tract or of some other animal?

Comment: The source is 'Textbook of HUMAN HISTOLOGY' by Inderber Singh and yes, we are talking on human uroepithilium.